# Why is Robert against liquid-plasma type screens?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In *Entrapment (1999)*, Aaron bought tools for the robbery & Robert reacted to it like this:

> "I specifically said **no** liquid-plasma screen".

I already checked it's advantages over the internet, it has upper hand over CRT, LED screens etc.

> Better motion tracking (little or no motion lag in fast moving
>   images).

Why is Robert against  liquid-plasma type screens?

Comment: Its probably just to show that he's a professional who is picky about the tools that he wants to use.  I doubt we are meant to be wondering why.  It may be power consumption, or robustness or anything - the point is he is being picky.